# MySQL, given default value is not taking to the desired column

Tags: mysql

I have created a table (RJY) with default value to one of its column. When I enter the command 'Describe  rjy;' its shows me default column with the value I gave,

when I insert data into my table using insert command, the column with default value is left blank and it is not taking the value which I gave. Below is my query please solve it.

```
mysql> insert into rjy (compy_id, reqrmnt, veh_type, go_type, weigh, l_start,l_end) 
values ('123456', '111', '12 ty', 'white cemt', '1 tons',    '',   'mumbai');
```

Here I gave default value to     "l_start"    field

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you give your field a value in the insert query (even it's it an empty value).

To have default value, you should change your insert as

```
insert into rjy (compy_id, reqrmnt, veh_type, go_type, weigh, ,l_end) 
values ('123456', '111', '12 ty', 'white cemt', '1 tons', 'mumbai');
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't include the column in your insert query. Do this:

```
insert into rjy (compy_id, reqrmnt, veh_type, go_type, weigh, l_end) 
values ('123456', '111', '12 ty', 'white cemt', '1 tons', 'mumbai');
```